# i want to set my index1 Jframe as main frame but it's giving errors

Tags: java

the IDE 'apache netbeans' is giving message "identifier expected illegal start of type".
I want set a default main JFrame in my main class...all the frames are in the same directory.
here is my code:

```
public class main {

   index1 dir = new index1();
  dir.setVisible(true);
}
```

it should call my frame but instead it's giving an error

Comment: You already have your answer, but for future reference: If "it's giving an error", *post the error*

Answer (score 0):

You can't have blocks of code directly under a class. They need to be in a constructor, method or initializer.

E.g., you can have them in your `main` method:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        index1 dir = new index1();
        dir.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```